# More efficient way of filtering list

Tags: python, performance, sorting, filter

(Disclaimer: not a good programmer, so I apologise in advance if my language is not precise.)

I have two list, and I want to identify all the items in the second list ("slope") that are smaller than -1, and does not have a previous duplicate. Then I wish to return the corresponding items in the first list (counter) where these two if-condition are met. (New list: "filter_count".)

This line of code does the job:

```
filter_count = [i for i,j in zip(counter, slope) if i-1 == slope.index( slope[int(i-1)] ) and j<=-1]
```

**But** when I am using the timer function between each of my line of code I see that the whole script use around 13 seconds to compute, but this specific line of code use around 99,9% of all the time! In other words, I assume I have written an extremely inefficient line here and wonder if I could do it much easier.

[image: For reference, this is an example on how the filter_count should be with these lists (in my real example it is much much longer)]

For reference, this is an example on how the filter_count should be with these lists (in my real example it is much much longer)

Comment: In general, try to avoid `.index` inside a `for`-loop. More often than not, there is a more efficient approach.

Comment: Also, if `counter` is always `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]` then you don't need it. You can replace `zip(counter, slope)` with `enumerate(slope, start=1)` (without optional argument `start=1`, `enumerate` starts at 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED:** (larger test lists)

The issue is that you are doing an `index` search for every element. This means the complexity of your algorithm is ***O(n<sup>2</sup>)***.

The `set` and `dict` solutions are better because they trade off memory to gain speed. Here is a very crude quick script for comparing the performance:

```py
import sys
from timeit import timeit


def generate_list(size: int) -> list:
    return list(range(-size//2, size//2))


def original_solution(counter: list, slope: list) -> list:
    filter_count = [i for i, j in zip(counter, slope) if i-1 == slope.index(slope[int(i-1)]) and j <= -1]
    return filter_count


def using_dictionary(counter: list, slope: list) -> list:
    """Inspired by Mechanic Pig"""
    mapping = {}
    for i, elem in zip(counter, slope):
        mapping.setdefault(elem, i)
    filter_count = [i for elem, i in mapping.items() if elem < -1]
    return filter_count


def using_set(counter: list, slope: list) -> list:
    """Inspired by Алексей Р"""
    s = set()
    filter_count = []
    for i, e in zip(counter, slope):
        if e not in s and e < 0:
            s.add(e)
            filter_count.append(i)
    return filter_count


def main():
    size, n = sys.argv[1:]
    print(f"List size: {size}, n: {n}")
    print("Time in seconds:")
    for func in [original_solution, using_dictionary, using_set]:
        name = func.__name__
        t = timeit(
            f'counter = slope = generate_list({size}); '
            f'{name}(counter, slope)',
            setup=f'from __main__ import generate_list, {name}',
            number=int(n)
        )
        print(f'{name:<18}', round(t, 4))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can call the script providing the desired list size and number or repetitions.

```bash
python test_script.py 10000 10
```

The results:

```
List size: 10000, n: 10
Time in seconds:
original_solution  3.5511
using_dictionary   0.0122
using_set          0.0093
```

I would speculate that the `set` solution is slightly better because both *adding* and *lookup* are *O(1)* in complexity and there is only one loop, making the entire algorithm ***O(n)***.

While the `dict` solution is technically also *O(n)*, it has to do two loops, meaning `2 * n` iterations in practice. So in the limit it is the same as the `set` solution, but in practice it will probably always be a bit slower.

Comment: See the comment in other answer about `counter` monotonicity assumption.

Comment: @JérômeRichard There is no monotonicity assumption anywhere here. See my response to your other comment.

Comment: From 16.43 seconds to 0.14 seconds! A variation between your using_set and Алексей did the trick. Very pedagogical with the printet time stamps, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Using `set` to prevent previous duplicate

```
counter = list(range(1, 16))
slope = [-229, -229, -13, -67, -99.4, -13, -43.8, -67, -13, -34.6, -52.2, -13, -29.6, 2.4, -13]
s = set()
filter_count = []
for i, e in zip(counter, slope):
    if e not in s and e < 0:
        s.add(e)
        filter_count.append(i)

print(filter_count)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 11, 13]
```

Comment: I think `counter` should be considered as in the OP question.

Comment: I suggest writing `if e not in s and e < 0:` rather than `if not e in s and e < 0:`

Comment: @JérômeRichard `counter` has been returned :)

Comment: @Stef yes, I agree

Comment: From 16.43 seconds to 0.14 seconds, thank you very much! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Use the dictionary to record the index of the first occurrence of each element, and then traverse to get the result:

```
>>> mapping = {}
>>> for i, elem in zip(counter, slope):    # or enumerate(slope, 1)
...     mapping.setdefault(elem, i)
...
>>> [i for elem, i in mapping.items() if elem < -1]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 11, 13]
```

Note: it depends on the dictionary ensure the insertion order in Python 3.7+. If you are using an earlier Python version, consider using `collections.OrderedDict`, or using `set` and `list` together.

Comment: Good solution though it implicitly assumes that `counter` is monotonic (ie. increasing). A two step approach would solve the problem in that case.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Please elaborate. How does this make any assumptions about the ordering of the `counter` list? The counter list may contain any kind of elements and the algorithm would still work.

Comment: @JérômeRichard You mean the comment about possibly using `enumerate` instead? Then yes, that would be the assumption. But as it stands, the algorithm makes zero assumptions about the contents or the ordering of the `counter` list other than that it has the same length as `slope`.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg The OP code check if there is a duplicate starting from the beginning of `slope`. If `counter` contains values like `[15, 14, 13, ..., 1]`, then the `mapping` will be set to indices bigger than the index of the duplicate. In this case, the code check if there is a duplicate starting from the end of `slope`. This is a different behaviour that should give different results. Said differently, the OP code duplicate check is independent of the previous iteration while the provided code is.

Comment: @JérômeRichard OK, now I see what you mean. The original solution and this `mapping` solution would in fact produce different results. But if anything, I would argue that either the original solution is wrong _or_ the stated requirements are ambiguous/unclear. Taking your `[15, ..., 1]` example, the original solution produces a list of elements from `counter` whose corresponding `slope` elements are in fact duplicates. The results would violate the stated requirements. I would argue that the **original** solution assumes monotonicity.

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not give the exact same result but still returns the index of each unique value. For example in case of the 1, 2 pair it returns 2 instead of 1 as it does in your result. Therefore still meets the requirements.
If you wanted the exact same result, you'd need to create a temporary dictionary (with `index: val`) and reverse the order before creating `slope_d` (`val: index`).

```py
# create list for testing
slope = [-229, -229, -13, -67, -99.4, -13, -43.85, -67, -13, -34.6, -52.27, -13, -29.61, 2.42, -13]

# transform to a dict with the values as keys
slope_d = {val: idx+1 for idx, val in enumerate(slope) if val <= -1}
# here lies the trick: since the keys of a dict are unique, 
# they will be overwritten if there's the same value present in the original list

# transform to list for output
filter_count = list(slope_d.values())
filter_count.sort()

print(filter_count)
```

Result:

```
[2, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```py
filter_count = [
    count for i, count in enumerate(counter)
    if slope[i]<-1 and count not in counter[:i]
]
```

Comment: This is still *O(n ^ 2)* in time complexity, not an improvement to the OP's code.

Comment: @blhsing I made an experiment using both as `counter` ans as `slope` the list `[x for x in range(-50000,50000)]`. @Harry implementation needed `44.08992550100038` seconds, mine needed `13.029368921000241` seconds and the one from @MechanicPig just `0.01898124799981815`. So mine it's clearly not the best but it's still a good improvement from the original code. Python is not C, you cannot just consider algorithmic complexity.

Comment: Not an improvement in terms of acceptability. 44 seconds and 13 seconds are both unacceptably slow when the problem can be solved practically instantaneously.